# Vanishing theorems for Čech and sheaf cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

So recently I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875866/looking-for-some-interesting-or-significant-results-from-cohomology) about interesting results from cohomology that would be suitable for a small first semester independent project in algebraic topology.

Čech cohomology was suggested there which seems interesting to me. I have seen the following theorem in a few different places:

> Let $X$ be a manifold of dimension $n$. Then if $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf (in the language of manifolds I think this corresponds to a vector bundle) then
>   \begin{equation} 
> H^{m} \left( X, \mathcal{F} \right) = 0 \quad \text{for } m > n.  
> \end{equation}

Now this seems to be a manifold equivalent of a vanishing theorem of Grothendieck found on page 208 of Hartshorne.

Could someone give me a reference to the first theorem I mentioned about the vanishing of Čech cohomology for manifolds? I haven't been able to find this in a text despite Googling, and I wonder if it had a particular name?

Secondly, is my claim that they are actually the same theorem in different contexts a correct interpretation or not?

Answer (score 1):

The key ingredient you need is the notion of **covering dimension**. The point is then that each $n$-dimensional manifold has covering dimension $n$ and each (say, paracompact Hausdorff) space $X$ of covering dimension $n$ satisfies $H^k(X,{\mathcal F})=0$ for $k>n$ and any sheaf ${\mathcal F}$ of abelian groups, simply because one can arrange for a sequence of coverings with empty $n+2$-fold intersections.  See for instance this  [wikipeda article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension) for the basic definitions and references.

Comment: What if $X$ is a compact complex manifold of dimension $n$?

Comment: @CTW: If $n$ stands for complex dimension  then covering dimension is $2n$. Hence, all sheaf cohomology vanish above dimension $2n$.